# Show custom stuff only if exist in wp

Tags: php, wordpress, footer

I've sidebar in my wp theme and i want appearance that only if value exist.

Photo of what I have:
http://prntscr.com/4lvfpk

Links of this part in `footer.php`

```
   <div class="Mysite">robertnicjoo</div>
    <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>"><div class="Mysite">Main page</div></a>
    <a href="<?php
                    // Value from Text Field
                    $Facebook = get_option('mysite_facebook');
                    echo $Facebook;
                    ?>"><div class="Mysite1">Facebook</div></a>
    <a href="<?php
                    // Value from Text Field
                    $Twitter = get_option('mysite_twitter');
                    echo $Twitter;
                    ?>"><div class="Mysite2">Twitter</div></a>
    <a href="<?php
                    // Value from Text Field
                    $Google_plus = get_option('mysite_google');
                    echo $Google_plus;
                    ?>"><div class="Mysite4">Google+</div></a>
    <a href="<?php
                    // Value from Text Field
                    $_youtube = get_option('mysite_youtube');
                    echo $_youtube;
                    ?>"><div class="Mysite5">Youtube</div></a>
    <a href="<?php bloginfo('rss2_url'); ?>"><div class="Mysite6">RSS</div></a>
```

Now if have value or not this part will appearance. I need just those parts that have value appearance.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you should check the variables before echoing the anchor href...

something like this:

```
...
<?php
// Value from Text Field
$Facebook = get_option('mysite_facebook');
if ( ! empty($Facebook)) {
?>
<a href="<?php echo $Facebook; ?>"><div class="Mysite1">Facebook</div></a>
<?php 
}
?>
...
```

Comment: This not work! btw this code will disable all parts!